# Opening one post instead of multiple posts

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I've written a blog that's supposed to fetch data from the database. But when I click on the read more link, it keeps opening all the posts that are in the db instead of selecting only one specific post that I've clicked. Can some kindly assist me with this issue?

**View**

```
@foreach($data as $aboutus)
        <div class="col-lg">
            <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$aboutus->image) }}" class="img-fluid shadow-lg" style="">
            <p class="mt-3 text-success fw-bold fs-5 text-lg-start">{{$aboutus->title}}</p>
            <p class="fs-6 text-lg-start"> {{$aboutus->description}}</p>
            <p class="text-success fw-bold text-lg-start"><a href="{{route('about.show',$aboutus->id)}}" class="text-success text-decoration-none">{{$aboutus->button}}</a></p>
            <!--<img src="images/hr-2.png" class="img-fluid float-start my-2">-->
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

**Controller**

```
public function show($id)
{
    //
    $data = AboutUs::find($id)->get();
    return view('about.show')->with(compact('data'));
    
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/about.show/{id:title}','App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController@show')->name('about.show');
```

Comment: Remove `->get()`, the `find()` method fetch only one record.

Comment: It still keeps fetching all the posts when I remove it.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: `{id:title}` in your route will use the title instead of the `id`